# Michvar goats' sneezing from Jerusalem incense?

Tags: geography, animals, mishna, smell

[*Tamid* chapter 3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%92_%D7%97) says (in my own free translation):

> One could smell from *Y'richo* the scent of the blend<sup>[1]</sup> of the *k'tores*. Rabbi *Eliezer b. Diglay* said, "Father's house had goats on Mt. *Michvar* that would sneeze from the scent of the blend<sup>[1]</sup> of the *k'tores*."

<sup>[1]</sup> or maybe "blending"

**How do we understand the statement of Rabbi *Eliezer b. Diglay*?**

*Mishnayos* use exaggeration. We see that [earlier in the same chapter of *Tamid*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37948&st=&pgnum=261), where it says "they watered [the sheep for] the *tamid* with a golden cup", which some interpret as being an exaggeration. So perhaps the first statement about the *k'tores* can be understod as an exaggeration — or, indeed, perhaps it is true literally. After all, *Y'richo* is only some fourteen miles from *Y'rushalayim*: perhaps a good breeze can carry a strong smell that far. I don't know.

But the statement of Rabbi *Eliezer b. Diglay* is a personal anecdote about goats his own family raised. I don't see how we can understand a personal anecdote as an exaggeration. On the other hand, it seems unlikely to be true literally: *Michvar*, the [*Rishon L'tziyon*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37948&st=&pgnum=267) says, is [*Ya'zer*, in *Gad*](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%91), across the river. While *Ya'zer*'s whereabouts are not known for certain (AFAIK), [it's listed](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2_%D7%99%D7%92) as being on the boundary of *Gad*, and [Wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%98_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9F), at least, claims that it's on the eastern boundary. (Any better source for that claim?) And he's not saying merely that there was some remnant of scent left there, but rather that it was strong enough to make goats sneeze.

Comment: Couldn't this be a description of a miracle?

Comment: @Isaac, it could be (though that's not how I've understood it), and if you know of a source that says it is then I'd love to learn of it.

Comment: My family would catch fish so large, Yonah and all the people of Ninveh could fit inside.  Why is so unheard of for someone to be exaggerating with personal stories?

Comment: @avi, possible. But it strikes me as unlikely in this case. If his statement is an exaggeration, then what does it add that the _tana kama_ hasn't already said?

Comment: Not only could one smell it, but even the goats would be agitated and sneeze from it.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53302

Answer (score 2):

It seems that others identify Michvar as [Machaerus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machaerus), site of a Hasmonean and later Herodian fortress, mentioned by Josephus, whose remnants are still extant. That's a lot closer to Jerusalem - about 28 miles as the crow flies. Granted, that's still twice as far as Jericho, but since about a third of that distance is over the Dead Sea, maybe indeed that would allow the smell to carry further.

Comment: who are the others?

Comment: @Menachem: whoever wrote the Wikipedia article, for starters. :) But it's also in an article by A.M. Luncz ([here](http://books.google.com/books?id=_dc8AAAAYAAJ&pg=PT189#v=onepage&q&f=false), page קצה).